# <f:attribute value="#{some EL expression}"> not found via getAttributes().containsKey()

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, attributes, el

I cannot retrieve attributes that contain EL inside my `ViewHandler`.

As a minimal example, here's my ViewHandler. It just looks for an attribute `"attributeName"` and prints out its value.

```
public class MiniViewHandler extends ViewHandlerWrapper
{
  private ViewHandler defaultViewHandler = null;

  public MiniViewHandler()
  {
  }

  public MiniViewHandler(ViewHandler defaultViewHandler)
  {
    super();
    this.defaultViewHandler = defaultViewHandler;
  }

  @Override
  public void renderView(FacesContext context, UIViewRoot viewToRender) throws IOException, FacesException
  {
    viewToRender.visitTree(VisitContext.createVisitContext(context),
            new VisitCallback()
            {

              @Override
              public VisitResult visit(VisitContext context, UIComponent target)
              {
                if (target.getAttributes().containsKey("attributeName"))
                {
                  System.out.println("Found it: " + target.getAttributes().get("attributeName"));
                }

                return VisitResult.ACCEPT;
              }
            }
    );

    defaultViewHandler.renderView(context, viewToRender);
  }

  @Override
  public ViewHandler getWrapped()
  {
    return defaultViewHandler;
  }
}
```

This is registered in the `faces-config.xml`. The xhtml that I'm hitting:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:body>
    <f:view>
        <f:attribute name="attributeName" value="#{2 + 5}"/>
    </f:view>
    <f:view>
        <f:attribute name="attributeName" value="2 + 5"/>
    </f:view>
</h:body>
</html>
```

The logged output shows that only the non-EL attribute was picked up.

```
INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Found it: 2 + 5
```

Comment: There's way too much ambiguity in the question. Better post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Okay, I'll put one together.

Comment: @BalusC I've added a minimal example that recreates what I'm seeing.

Comment: Helpful. The mistake is in `containsKey()`. This doesn't search in value expressions. You'd need to just `get()` it outright and check for `null`. I'll post an answer later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mistake is here:

```
if (target.getAttributes().containsKey("attributeName"))
```

You're using `containsKey()` to check if the property has been specified. This however won't work if the attribute is a `ValueExpression`. Here's an extract from [`UIComponent#getAttributes()` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getAttributes%28%29) with emphasis:

> #### getAttributes
>
> `public abstract java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object> getAttributes()`
>
> Return a mutable `Map` representing the attributes (and properties, see below) associated wth this `UIComponent`, keyed by attribute name (which must be a `String`). The returned implementation must support all of the standard and optional `Map` methods, plus support the following additional requirements:
>
> - The `Map` implementation must implement the `java.io.Serializable` interface.
> - Any attempt to add a `null` key or value must throw a `NullPointerException`.
> - Any attempt to add a key that is not a `String` must throw a `ClassCastException`.
> - **If the attribute name specified as a key matches a property of this `UIComponent`'s implementation class, the following methods will have special behavior:**
>
>   - **`containsKey()` - Return `false`.**
>   - `get()` - If the property is readable, call the getter method and return the returned value (wrapping primitive values in their corresponding wrapper classes); otherwise throw `IllegalArgumentException`.
>   - `put()` - If the property is writeable, call the setter method to set the corresponding value (unwrapping primitive values in their corresponding wrapper classes). If the property is not writeable, or an attempt is made to set a property of primitive type to `null`, throw `IllegalArgumentException`.
>   - `remove()` - Throw `IllegalArgumentException`.

Thus, it always returns `false` for `containsKey` for component's properties (read: component's `ValueExpression`s). That's because dynamic properties are not stored in the attribute map, but instead in the component instance itself via [`UIComponent#setValueExpression()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#setValueExpression(java.lang.String,%20javax.el.ValueExpression)) calls. They're only resolved when calling `get()`.

You basically need to change the wrong line as follows, this also works for "static" attributes:

```
Object value = target.getAttributes().get("attributeName");
if (value != null) {
    System.out.println("Found it: " + value);
}
```

If you would like to check if the attribute is actually being set, even though it would evaluate `null` like `value="#{bean.returnsNull}"`, then you'd instead like to check if [`UIComponent#getValueExpression()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getValueExpression(java.lang.String)) doesn't return `null`.

```
if (target.getValueExpression("attributeName") != null) {
    System.out.println("Found it: " + target.getAttributes().get("attributeName"));
}
```

This does in turn however not work for "static" attributes. You could just combine the checks if necessary, depending on the concrete functional requirements.

Comment: Great, that works, thanks. Quick question - the EL doesn't appear to be evaluated (I get a value of "2 + 5" back). Is there any way to have it evaluate automatically?

Comment: It should. Apparently you got value of `<f:attribute name="attributeName" value="2 + 5"/>` instead of `<f:attribute name="attributeName" value="#{2 + 5}"/>`

Comment: I did handle the two cases differently, so I printed them differently: INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-2) Found it: 2 + 5
INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-2) Attribute Found it: 2 + 5

Comment: Never seen this problem. Can't reproduce on Mojarra 2.2.7 either. Which JSF impl/version? Tried the latest? Are you sure you're running the code you think you're running?

Comment: I think there's a good chance I'm being retarded - I'll experiment further. Thanks for the help though.